# No Content-Length Header for App

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, nginx

I have a newsstand application that uses a bar to show download progress. It works by getting the content-length from the file download. This used to work on our development server, however we use an nginx server for production and it doesn't seem to be returning a content-length header.

Does anyone know why this would be or a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lack of a Content-Length header is likely caused by you having compression enabled on your live server but not on your dev server. Because Nginx compresses data as it's sent, it's not possible to send a Content-Length header at the start of the response, as the server can't know what size the data will be after it's compressed.

If you require a Content-Length header for a download progress then the best option is to compress the content yourself, set the Content-Length header to the size of the compressed data, and then serve the compressed data.

Although this will be slightly slower for the first user to download that piece of content, you can use it as an effective caching mechanism if you use unique filenames for the compressed files, with the filename generated from the parameters in the users request. You can also then use Nginx's [x-sendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) ability to reduce the load on your server.

btw if you're using Amazon CloudFront CDN (and probably others) you really ought to be setting the Content-Length header as they can serve partial (aka corrupt) files, if there is no Content-Length header and the download from your server to CloudFront is interrupted during transfer.